# Where do I get a webhook url for a facebook messenger bot?

Tags: hooks, uri

I want to check out and explore this interesting drupal module made by the white house: https://github.com/WhiteHouse/fb_messenger_bot

I've successfully installed drupal on my Mac thru MAMP. I've also enabled the said module. But I got stuck on this step of the installation instructions as stated in the README:

*"Complete steps 1-4 outlined in Facebook's quickstart documentation including the copying of the page access token in step 3 (note: this module sets up the webhook at /webhook/contact)"*

To be more specific, Facebook is asking for a callback url, but I can't find it. Whenever I type https://localhost:8888/webhook/contact as the callback url, Facebook gives me this error message:

*The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 56; curl_error = Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT; HTTP Status Code = 502; HTTP Message = Private address*

I am completely new to drupal and MAMP. Any help that would point me towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in a local development environment, you will need a publicly accessible IP address or domain name to route the FB request to your local server messenger bot webhooks.

Comment: I see. so that is why the facebook isn't accepting my url... may i ask, how do i make a publicly accessible domain name in drupal? thanks for the reply

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to get a webhost and / or register a domain name. Then you can publish your website there for development. There are other ways to route the public WAN traffic to your local server, but that's a bit more technically difficult.